# Oracle DB equivalent of on duplicate key update

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to execute the following MySQL-query in Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,10) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = 10;
```

Is there something else besides `merge`? I just don't understand it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would need to use a `MERGE`.  Something like

```
MERGE INTO users dest
  USING( SELECT 1 user_id, 10 points FROM dual) src
     ON( dest.user_id = src.user_id )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET points = src.points
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT( user_id, points ) 
     VALUES( src.user_id, src.points );
```

Comment: Be careful using UPDATE for counter increment! you have to use aliases for both src and dst,  UPDATE SET COUNTER = dst.COUNTER + src.COUNTER, otherwise it will take src value by default!  UPDATE SET COUNTER = COUNTER + src.COUNTER (uses src.COUNTER by default for left argument)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use MERGE, you can try:

```
begin
   INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,10);

   exception
      when dup_val_on_index then
         update users
            set points = 10
          where id = 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MERGE INTO users u
USING (SELECT 1 as id FROM dual) a
ON a.id = u.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET u.points = 10
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, points) VALUES (1, 10);
```