# Why I get error message when transfer INSERT method to Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I get error message which a little bit confusing me and have no idea what I made wrong here

```
FUNCTION ADD_TOKEN(p_userID IN INT,p_token IN VARCHAR2,p_type IN VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*TokenExists*/
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_notifications_token (userId, token, type) 
    VALUES (p_userID, p_token , p_type) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
       UPDATE token = p_token, created_date = SYSTIMESTAMP;
END ADD_TOKEN;
```

I get error message

```
Error(51,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I put this function inside `PACKAGE` where I store all my function `(arround 50 functions)`
Does anyone know what is wrong here ? Where did I made mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle [does not support the SQL Server syntax `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10589350/1509264). Use a `MERGE` statement instead.

```sql
FUNCTION ADD_TOKEN(
  p_userID IN user_notifications_token.userID%TYPE,
  p_token  IN user_notifications_token.token%TYPE,
  p_type   IN user_notifications_token.type%TYPE
) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS 
  rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO user_notifications_token dst
  USING (
    SELECT p_userID AS userID,
           p_token AS token,
           p_type AS type
    FROM   DUAL
  ) src
  ON ( src.userId = dst.userID )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET token = src.token, type = src.type
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( userId, token, type ) VALUES ( src.userId, src.token, src.type );

  -- Do stuff
  
  RETURN rc;
END ADD_TOKEN;
```

Then if you do:

```sql
DECLARE
  rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  rc := package_name.ADD_TOKEN( 1, 'ABC', 'A' );
  rc := package_name.ADD_TOKEN( 1, 'DEF', 'D' );
END;
/
```

The table will contain:

> ```
> USERID | TOKEN | TYPE
> -----: | :---- | :---
>      1 | DEF   | D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e50e698c63bef37bdd9beed473a4ebd)*

Comment: Could you please provide some example of full answer I would be very thankfull

Comment: Can I use currson here ? `OPEN rc FOR` and `RETURN rc;` ?

Comment: @don_julian Yes, you can. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=adcca857bbfbd60374433d0192c062b2)